# Growth Curve Model with time-invariant covariates- standardized CIs

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, growth-model

I ran a growth curve model (GCM) with covariates and used the 95% bootstrapping CIs to interpret the effects of the covariates on the intercept and slopes. I noticed that the upper bound of the CI of the standardized effects on the slope is above 1. I am wondering about this because normally the standardized effects are between -1 and 1. I have read that a reason can be a high correlation between the predictors, but there is no high bivariate correlation between the variables. Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks, this would be really helpful for me.

Comment: How exactly did you calculate these intervals? When you say 'standardized effects', do you mean shifted by the mean & scaled by the standard deviation? These will not be within [-1, 1] - any observation more than a standard deviation from the mean will be outside that range.

Answer (score 2):

In any multiple regression model--including a growth curve model with multiple correlated covariates of the growth factors--standardized regression (path) coefficients are not bound by [-1, 1]. Unlike correlation coefficients, partial standardized regression coefficients > |1| are possible and are not necessarily indicative of an improper solution ("Heywood case"). Partial standardized regression coefficients > |1| can occur with highly correlated predictor variables and/or in the presence of suppressor variables. Therefore, the values that you see in your CI are not necessarily concerning.

Comment: Christian Geiser, thanks a lot for this helpful comment. In my studies, i learned that normally stand. coefficents, like beta coefficents can be interpreted as effect sizes, is that wrong?

Comment: Both standardized and unstandardized regression coefficients both measure the linear association between two variables (potentially controlling for other variables). So yes, they can be seen as effect size measures. Standardized regression coefficients can sometimes be difficult to interpret, i.e., in situations of suppression/strong collinearity.